# insertDataforTableName returns wrong object type

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm building out some new functionality in my app which is essentially just old code copied for a new class type. Before it was creating and displaying vehicles, and now it's creating and displaying books, however it's not behaving as expected.

I want to persist the data, so here is the code which creates a new ManagedObject, which should return a pointer to the object:

```
vehicle = [[MyCoreDataManager sharedManager] insertDataforTableName:@"MyVehicle"];
```

This line returns an object of type `MyVehicle`, which is what I want. `MyVehicle` is a class which inherits from `NSManagedObject` and has its own methods which are immediately used after inserting.

Now I want to have the same exact arrangement, except with a `MyBook` object. However, when I run:

```
book = [[MyCoreDataManager sharedManager] insertDataforTableName:@"MyBook"];
```

The above line of code returns an object of type `NSManagedObject`, which is **wrong** because I can't access the `MyBook` methods because it's an `NSManagedObject` and not a `MyBook`. I even tried type casting, but it doesn't work. The fact that it is an `NSManagedObject` and not a `MyBook` is causing my app to crash with an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` exception because I am trying to call a method which is not recognized by the object at runtime. Your thoughts are appreciated.

My understanding of the problem is that somehow the `MyBook` class is not properly declared or has some subtle issue in its .h or .m file which is causing it not to link up at runtime. Or some kind of problem with the .xcdatamodeld entity definition.

Comment: Does the definition of the "MyBook" entity in the data model specify "MyBook" as its class?  What does `insertDataforTableName` do?

Comment: You solved it for me! It turns out that I never specified the class for the entity in the data model. Being a CoreData beginner, I thought all I had to do was create an entity with the name `MyBook` and I'd be set. Turns out I also had to specify the actual class it's linked to which makes perfect sense. Feel free to pen up the answer and I will accept it and then beef it up for you. Or tomorrow I can answer it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob Mayoff was correct to ask:

> Does the definition of the "MyBook" entity in the data model specify "MyBook" as its class?

Because in this case it did not. If you ever want to create a new entity in your data model, be sure to specify the actual class that it is associated with in the right hand toolbar. It's pretty easy to miss this step, if you ask me.